# Bag of Words encoding for Python with vocabulary

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to implement new columns into my ML model. A numeric column should be created if a **specific** word is found in the text of the scraped data. For this I created a dummy script for testing.

```
import pandas as pd

bagOfWords = ["cool", "place"]
wordsFound = ""

mystring = "This is a cool new place"
mystring = mystring.lower()

for word in bagOfWords:
    if word in mystring: 
        wordsFound = wordsFound + word + " "

print(wordsFound)
pd.get_dummies(wordsFound)
```

The output is

```
    cool place
0   1
```

This means there is one sentence "0" and one entry of "cool place". This is not correct. Expectations would be like this:

```
    cool place
0   1    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a different solution, as I cound not find any way forward. Its a simple direct hot encoding. For this I enter for every word I need a new column into the dataframe and create the encoding directly.

```
vocabulary = ["achtung", "suchen"]

for word in vocabulary:
    df2[word] = 0

    for index, row in df2.iterrows():
        if word in row["title"].lower():
            df2.set_value(index, word, 1)
```